# Lightweight Message Bus with broadcasting and routing capabilities?

Tags: message-queue, event-driven-design, mom, message-bus, event-queue

I am trying to find the most light-weight message bus (queue?) that can handle the following:

1. Producer A subscribes to the bus. The bus is specified via a well    known form of identification (like a name, a socket or something).
2. Consumer B subscribes to the same bus and registers to only a         certain kind of messages.
3. Consumer C subscribes to the same bus and registers to another kind of messages that overlaps with that of B.
4. Producer A puts a message in the bus such that both B and C are interested in. Both B and C receive the message (not just one of them, but both of them).

A, B, C and the bus are residing in different machines.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best using a queue (such as ActiveMQ) for this and for the `lightweight` requirement, you can use MQTT as the underlying protocol which is extremely lightweight.

See:
http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html

http://mqtt.org/

For your scenario:

1. Your producer A will connect to the queue
2. Your consumer B will connect to the same queue and listens to a topic (for instance `/topic/onlyBisInterested`). It will also subscribe to `/topic/everyoneIsInterested`
3. Your consumer C will connect to the queue and listens to `/topic/everyoneIsInterested`

   4. Your producer will publish a message to `/topic/everyoneIsInterested` and both B and C will receive this message.

You can play around with the topics a lot. You can have topic matching rules on a wildcard basis, on an exact basis or any combination thereof. There are also levels of hierarchy (such as /a/b/*) that can be setup which will accept (/a/b/c or /a/b/d or anything else).

You can also transfer your data over SSL and use authentication if required and use message persistence and guaranteed delivery in case one/many of your node(s) go down.

I recommend reading the official documentation and deciding if it's good enough for you. There are plenty of other free or commercial queues available, most/all of which will satisfy your requirements since they are very standard.

Answer (score 0):

We've written a peer-to-peer message bus, Zebus, based on ZeroMq (transport), Cassandra (peer discovery and persistence) and Protobuf (serialisation).  It supports [routing of messages based on properties of the messages](https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/Zebus/wiki/Routing).

It is open source and production tested https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/Zebus

Zebus is being actively developed and it is in heavy in-house production use. Currently there is only a .NET language binding.